# Chrome not picking up margin-left style, works in FF and IE

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a paragraph of text to indent, it works in FireFox and Internet Explorer, but does not work in Chrome. The code is:

HTML

`<p class="text-left-ten">What does this does hopefully is indent by 10 %. I hope so! Otherwise....</p>`

CSS

`.text-left-ten { margin-left:10%; }`

I tried using padding with the same result, works in FF and IE but not Chrome.
Also, it does not appear in the Matched CSS Rules in the Developer Tools window.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dBKvB/ illustrates that the css is working perfectly fine. Please provide more context so we can see why it's failing for you.

Comment: You can try just the left property of css instead of margin-left.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found out it was Chrome caching it, the old Ctrl-F5 thing didn't work. Have diabled caching in the Devleopment tools and all is good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I found out it was Chrome caching it, the old Ctrl-F5 thing didn't work. Have diabled caching in the Devleopment tools and all is good now :)